# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when trying to persist an ArrayList of Objects which utilise inheritence

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I have 3 classes: Person, Car and Model.

Person has an ArrayList property defined:

```
List<Car> cars;
```

Car is an abstract class which class Model extends, I.e.

```
@PersistenceCapable
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceStrategy.SUBCLASS_TABLE)
public abstract class Car {

  @PrimaryKey
  @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
  protected Key key;

  public Car() {
  }

}
```

Model extends Car:

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class Model extends Car {

  public Model() {
  }

}
```

I load a Person object and create a new Car object, I.e.

```
Person personObj = pm.getObjectById(Person.class, key);
Car newCar = new Model();
```

I then try to persist the new Car by adding it to the "cars" property in the Person Class, I.e.

```
personObj.getCars().add(newCar);
```

However, when I try this App Engine throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at org.datanucleus.store.mapped.scostore.FKListStore.<init>(FKListStore.java:133)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreFKListStore.<init>(DatastoreFKListStore.java:41)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreManager.newFKListStore(DatastoreManager.java:528)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mapped.MappedStoreManager.getBackingStoreForCollection(MappedStoreManager.java:729)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mapped.MappedStoreManager.getBackingStoreForField(MappedStoreManager.java:646)
    at org.datanucleus.sco.backed.List.<init>(List.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInstance_(Runtime.java:112)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInstance(Runtime.java:120)
    at org.datanucleus.util.ClassUtils.newInstance(ClassUtils.java:94)
    at org.datanucleus.sco.SCOUtils.newSCOInstance(SCOUtils.java:164)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.AbstractContainerMapping.replaceFieldWithWrapper(AbstractContainerMapping.java:426)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.CollectionMapping.postInsert(CollectionMapping.java:165)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreRelationFieldManager.runPostInsertMappingCallbacks(DatastoreRelationFieldManager.java:217)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreRelationFieldManager.access$200(DatastoreRelationFieldManager.java:48)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreRelationFieldManager$1.apply(DatastoreRelationFieldManager.java:116)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreRelationFieldManager.storeRelations(DatastoreRelationFieldManager.java:81)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreFieldManager.storeRelations(DatastoreFieldManager.java:955)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastorePersistenceHandler.storeRelations(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:546)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertPostProcess(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:304)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertObjects(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:256)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertObject(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:240)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.internalMakePersistent(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:3185)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.makePersistent(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:3161)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.persistObjectInternal(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1298)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.persistObject(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1170)
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoMakePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:669)
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.makePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:694)
```

This sounds much like a similar question that was raised here: http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/adf298a9a5b4bd03

Has anyone else seen this issue before?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, `personObj.getCars()` returns `List <Car> cars;`

I am making inferences due to the fact that you haven't given much code, but just having `List <Car> cars;` will set `cars` to `null`.

I am not sure how the app engine platform works, but it may be sending out an AIOOBE instead of a NPE.

Whatever the reason, you should be instantiating... `cars = new ArrayList();`

Comment: If `cars` were null, he'd be getting a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the root cause of your problem (if it is, it's a rather unintuitive way for the error to show itself), but JDO on App Engine does not support polymorphism. Try your example without the abstract 'Car' class.